# $L^p$-Regularity for distributional solutions of elliptic boundary value problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am looking for a reference on the following problem (or related problems):

If you have $\forall \varphi\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $w\in L^{p'}$ (where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} =1 $):

$$ 0 = \int\limits_\Omega w (-\Delta\varphi + f\varphi), $$

i.e. $w$ is a "very weak solution" of

\begin{align*}
 -\Delta w + fw & = 0 \text{ in } \Omega\\
 w & =0 \text{ on } \partial\Omega.
\end{align*}

where $f$ is continuous (maybe more).
Do you know any reference that in this case, it is indead $w\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ ?
I looked at various other posts, but didn't find a reference for this case.
Thank you.

Comment: $w$ is a distribution. I wonder if you can reach a contradiction assuming $\text{order}(w) \ge 1$. This way you'd get $\text{order}(w) = 0$, a good start.

Comment: ok, I never worked with the order of a distribution, I read the definition, but I can't see why this would help me (or even how to show $\text{order}(w)=0). Could you give me another hint?

Comment: I don't know a reference, but for the case $p=2$ you can prove passing to the Fourier transform that $u\in L^2$, $\Delta u\in L^2$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ implies $u\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)\cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$, at least for regular $\Omega$ (try to prove it in $\mathbb R^n$ first). For the case $p\neq 2$ I think you need some harmonic analysis, in particular Calderon-Zygmund estimates

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference that maybe can help you. It's

> Y.Z. Chen, L.C. Wu - *Second Order Elliptic Equations and Elliptic Systems*

in particular chapter 3, Theorem 3.5 is close to the result you want with $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$, however it's not exactly that. I'll try to briefly summarize the result here. Consider the equation
$$\Delta w=f$$
and call $N:C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$
the operator that sends $f$ to the special solution $w=\Gamma * f$, where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution. Consider also, for fixed indices $i,j$, the operator
$$T_{ij}:C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$$
that sends $f$ to $D_{ij}Nf$. Then by the reference above, $T_{ij}$ is of strong type $(p,p)$, which means $\|T_{ij}f\|_p\leq C_p \|f\|_p$. In particular, by density of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, $T_{ij}$ can be extended to $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ to obtain that for any $f\in L^p$
$$\|D^2 w\|_p\leq C \|f\|_p$$
and you can conclude that also $Dw\in L^p$ e.g. by Gagliardo-Nirenberg. In this way you also have an estimate $\|w\|_{W^{2,p}}\leq C\|f\|_{L^p}$.

This is not exactly what you needed, but I hope it can be helpful anyway. For $\Omega$ bounded and Lipschitz I think you can use a partition of unity to reduce to the case in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found this inequality many times regarding $L^p$-regularity for elliptic PDEs. My problem is: In most cases, the results are given only for the Laplacian, but I am looking for something for general elliptic PDEs. For example something like Thm. 10.2.2 in Jost's Partial Differential Equtions. Do you know anything like this?

Comment: @Eva Unfortunately not, but I'll think about it. For now I just have some observations: for *very weak* solutions some care must be used. Already in $L^2$ a result like Theorem 10.2.2 you're citing can not hold without boundary conditions. If I'm not mistaken there's an example of $w\in L^2(D)$, where $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ is the unit disk, with $\Delta w=0$, but $u\not\in W^{1,2}$, so it does not even have controlled first derivatives. However if you require $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ the result is true, as I already mentioned in a previous comment